# How to remove certain letters from input string in Mediawiki?

Tags: replace, mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

I've created a new Wiki entry, which uses a Wiki template called `filter`. This is how it looks:

```
{{filter
|ListofFruits= 
* Apple
* Orange
* Banana
}}
```

Now I want to retrieve the list in my filter template, but without the `*` and without a linebreak. As a result the template has to output all these fruits like this:

```
Apple Orange Banana
```

How can this be done? I searched the documentaries, but did not find anything about filtering parameters.

Comment: Do you want the template to parse the string `* Apple\n * Orange...`, and output `Apple Orange...`?

Comment: @leo Yes, but \n is not written in the parameter. I already tried it using {{#replace:{{{ListofFruits}}}|\n *|}} but this did not work.

Comment: And using a more convenient format for the template, e.g. `{{filter
|fruits=Apple;Orange;Banana}}` is not an option?

Comment: Unfortunately not, because I need this list for a infobox

Comment: I don't get it, if you are using the template in an ordinary infobox, why, can't you just use a format like {{filter |fruits=Apple;Orange;Banana}}, and then print it out anyhow you want? If you need more than just search-and-replace functionality you could use the Extension:Arrays, to recreate the list anyhow you's like, e.g. as `Apple Orange ...` in one place, and as `* Apple\n *Orange\ ...` in another!

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really, really need the input to the template to be in that very format (e.g. because it's populated by a bot that you don't control), consider using a more parsing friendly format, e.g.:

```
{{filter
  |ListofFruits=Apple;Orange;Banana
}}
```

Then you can either use replace, or the more advanced possibilities of the [Arrays extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Arrays) to format the list like you want.

**With replace:**

```
<!-- Create a bullet list -->
*{{#replace:{{{ListofFruits}}}|;|<nowiki />
* 
}}

<!-- Create a space separated list -->
{{#replace:{{{ListofFruits}}}|;|&nbsp;}}
```

**With arrays:**

```
<!-- Define array a -->
{{#arraydefine:a|{{{ListofFruits}}}|;}}

<!-- Print a as bullet list -->
{{#arrayprint:a ||@@@@|<nowiki />
*@@@@ }}

<!-- Print a as space separated list -->
{{#arrayprint:a|&nbsp;}}
```